# Google+ Signin for Android: Unable to get "Choose an account" popup

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate Google+ signin on Android.

Created a test app using this code https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5170508
Test app works perfectly. Launcher class looks something like this

```
public class SignInTestActivity extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, OnClickListener,
    OnAccessRevokedListener {

.
.
.google+ signin functions from https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/5170508
.


}
```

Now i want to integrate Google+ signin on an actual app.
The structure of my app looks like this.

Home.java is the launcher class

```
public class Home extends Activity{

..
..
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ..
    ..
    ..
    setContentView(R.layout.global);
    final LoginViewCtrl lvc = new LoginViewCtrl(dataMgr, this);
    lvc.setListener(this);
    viewMgr.pushView(lvc);


}
```

I added Google+ sign functions in LoginViewCtrl class.
When i click on 'Sign in' button it shows progressbar loading sign but never shows "Choose an account" popup populated with my google accounts.

Should i paste LoginViewCtrl class here if it helps in finding a solution?